# How do I massage data from multiple columns and multiple files into single data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
  sp_id         sp_dt          v1      v1      v3

x1|x2|x30|x40   2018-10-07     100     200     300 
x1|x2|x30|x40   2018-10-14     80       80      90  
x1|x2|x30|x40   2018-10-21     34       35      36 
x1|x2|x31|x41   2018-10-07     100     200     300 
x1|x2|x31|x41   2018-10-14     80       80      90  
x1|x2|x31|x41   2018-10-21     34       35      36   
....
x1|x2|x39|x49   2018-10-21     340      350     36
```

and an excel file that has the following data(and each sheet in the excel may contain multiple variables like v4, v5 as shown below, possibly v6 in another sheet):

```
Variable      sp_partid1  sp_partid2    2018-10-07  ... 2018-10-21
  v4            x30         x40              160     ...   154
  v4            x31         x41              59      ...   75
  ....
  v4            x39         x49              75      ...   44
  v5            x30         x40              16      ...   24
  v5            x31         x41              59      ...   79
  ....
  v5            x39         x49              75      ...   34
```

sp_partid1 and sp_partid2 are optional columns. They are "part of sp_id" column in the top data frame. The file can have none or, in this specific example, upto 4 such columns, each a part of sp_id column in the data frame on the top.

The final output should look like:

```
  sp_id         sp_dt          v1      v1      v3     v4    v5
x1|x2|x30|x40   2018-10-07     100     200     300    160   16  
x1|x2|x30|x40   2018-10-14     80       80      90    ...   ...
x1|x2|x30|x40   2018-10-21     34       35      36    154   24
x1|x2|x31|x41   2018-10-07     100     200     300    59    59
x1|x2|x31|x41   2018-10-14     80       80      90    ...   ...
x1|x2|x31|x41   2018-10-21     34       35      36    75    79
....
x1|x2|x39|x49   2018-10-21     340      350     36    44    34
```

Edit1 starts:
How is the output generated?

```
get a list of variables
check if the variable(say v4 in this case) exists in any sheet
if it does:
  does it have any "part of sp_id" 
  #In the example shown sp_partid1 and sp_partid2 of excel sheets 
  #are part of sp_id of dataframe.
  if yes:
  #it means the part of sp_id is common for all values. (x1|x2) in this case. 
      add a new column to dataframe, v4, which has sp_id, sp_dt and,
      the value of that date 
  if no:
  #it means the whol sp_id is common for all values. (x1|x2|x3|x4) in this case and not shown in example.
      add a new column to dataframe, v4, and copy the value under the appropriate dates in excel sheet into corresponding v4 values and sp_dt
```

As an example 160 is the value under 2018-10-07 for v4, x30, x40 so v4 in the final output shows 160 in the first row.

Edit1 ends:

I started my code with:

```
df # is the top data frame which I have not gotten around to using yet
var_value # gets values in a loop like 'v4, v5...'

sheets_dict = {name: pd.read_excel('excel_file.xlsx', sheet_name = name, parse_dates = True) for name in sheets}

for key, value in sheets_dict.items():
   if 'Variable' in value.columns:
   # 'Variable' column exists in this sheet
      if var_value in value['Variable'].values:
      # var_value exists in 'Variable' column (say, v4)
          for column in value.columns:
             if column.startswith('sp_'):
                #Do something with column values, then map the values etc
```

Comment: I really do not understand what you are trying to do. How is your output generated? I do not understand the logic behind it.

Comment: I edited the OP to reflect the logic on how the output is generated.

Answer (score 0):

assuming one of your excel sheet has the below data,

```
  Variable sp_partid1 sp_partid2  2018-10-07  2018-10-08  2018-10-21
0       v4        x30        x40         160        10.0         154
1       v4        x31        x41          59         NaN          75
2       v4        x32        x42          75        10.0          44
3       v5        x30        x40          16        10.0          24
4       v5        x31        x41          59        10.0          79
5       v5        x32        x42          75        10.0          34
```

you can use a combination of pandas `melt` and `pivot_table` function to get the desired result.

```
import pandas as pd
book= pd.read_excel('del.xlsx',sheet_name=None)
for df in book.values():
    df=df.melt(id_vars=['Variable','sp_partid1','sp_partid2'], var_name="Date", value_name="Value")
    # concatenate strings of two columns separated by a '|'
    df['sp_id'] = df['sp_partid1'] +'|'+ df['sp_partid2']
    df = df.loc[:,['Variable', 'sp_id','Date','Value']]
    df = df.pivot_table('Value', ['sp_id','Date'], 'Variable').reset_index( drop=False )
    print(df)  

>> output
Variable    sp_id        Date     v4    v5
0         x30|x40  2018-10-07  160.0  16.0
1         x30|x40  2018-10-08   10.0  10.0
2         x30|x40  2018-10-21  154.0  24.0
3         x31|x41  2018-10-07   59.0  59.0
4         x31|x41  2018-10-08    NaN  10.0
5         x31|x41  2018-10-21   75.0  79.0
6         x32|x42  2018-10-07   75.0  75.0
7         x32|x42  2018-10-08   10.0  10.0
8         x32|x42  2018-10-21   44.0  34.0
```

reading excel workbook with sheet_name=None will give a dictionary with `worksheet name` as `key` and a `data frame` as `value`

Comment: Thanks Shijith. I am trying to apply some of what you have mentioned to see if I can arrive at what I need.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying do makes sense, but it is quite a long sequence of operations, so it is normal that you have some trouble implementing it. I think you should step back to the higher level of abstraction of **relational databases**, and use the high-level dataframe operations offered by pandas.

Let's summarize what you want to do, in terms of high-level operations:

1. Change the format of the `sheet_dicts` dataframes, such that it has the same data, but presented differently

```py
   id3           id4        date            v4         v5       
   x30           x40        2018-10-07      160        154
   x31           x41        2018-10-08      30         10
```

2. Split the ids of the original dataframe in several columns.
3. **Join** the resulting dataframes with the original one **on id and date**.

I can't give you a precise implementation are you specification is still quite vague, even though the global goal is clear. Also, I don't have a reference to provide to guide you with relational database, but I highly recommend that you get informed, it will save you a lot of time, especially if you often have to perform such tasks.

Comment: I don't quite understand the reference to relational databases.